# Java matcher.matches() returning false when it should be true

Tags: java, regex

So I'm having an issue, I need to check for simple beginning and ending HTML tags in a string. The beginning tag I haven't had any problems with it is when I am trying to find the ending tag that I have issues.

```
private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;
private Pattern endPattern;
private Matcher endMatcher;

private static final String HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<([a-zA-Z]+)>";
public boolean hasCorrectHTML(String checking)
{
    boolean ret=true;
    pattern=Pattern.compile(HTML_TAG_PATTERN);
    matcher=pattern.matcher(checking);

    while(matcher.find() && ret)
    {
        String htmlEndTag="</"+matcher.group(1)+">";

        endPattern=Pattern.compile(htmlEndTag);
        endMatcher=endPattern.matcher(checking.substring(matcher.end()));

        ret=endMatcher.matches();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

In the above code I find the first tag of something and then I continue to find the ending tag. I know there are going to be some future issues with this setup, this is a work in progess. However, the check for the ending tag does not work. As far as I can see my logic is sound. I am taking whatever the tag is and checking for its end tag through . I then throw that into a second pattern and then check for a match using the second matcher.
My text string is "`<b>this test</b>`". It detects `<b>` just fine but when I check for a match on `</b>` it always returns false. I've asked peers for any idea why this would be happening but they are at a loss too. I have no idea why this would be happening, any ideas? What am I missing here?

Comment: matches() tests if the *whole string* matches with the pattern. Use find(), as you correctly did to find the opening tag. Or better, use a real HTML parser like JSoup. Using regexps for HTML parsing is a dead-end.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I would use a real HTML parser but for this purpose I was specifically told to do it this way. I know it is stupid and I don't agree with it either but it isn't always about me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your question, and I don't know if I solve your problem, if not, please give me some examples to quickly understand your question.

```
private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;
private Pattern endPattern;
private Matcher endMatcher;

private static final String HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<([a-zA-Z]+)>[^<]*";
public boolean hasCorrectHTML(String checking)
{
    boolean ret=true;
    pattern=Pattern.compile(HTML_TAG_PATTERN);
    matcher=pattern.matcher(checking);

    while(matcher.find() && ret)
    {
        String htmlEndTag="</"+matcher.group(1)+">";

        endPattern=Pattern.compile(htmlEndTag);

        String endChecking = checking.substring(matcher.end());
        endMatcher=endPattern.matcher(endChecking);

        ret=endMatcher.matches();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Okay so lets say I pass <b>this test</b>. My first html pattern will find the beginning tag (<b>). If it finds anything, which in this case it will, it will enter the while loop, it takes the content of the first find and creates an end tag check for it like </b>. It will then check the rest of the string for that end tag. The problem is I am using .matches() instead of .find() as @JB_Nizet mentioned, where .matches() checks to see if the whole string is </b> where .find() check for each individual </b>.

Comment: OK, anyway, it works if change HTML_TAG_PATTERN from "<([a-zA-Z]+)>" to "<([a-zA-Z]+)>[^<]*"

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so this was answered by JB Nizet, but inplace of endMatcher.matches() I should put endMatcher.find() instead because .matches() checks to see if the whole string matches the regex where .find() check for portions of the string that match the regex.